# How to filter Correct Phone numbers using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of phone numbers(indian formats) in one column which contains unused symbols. I am trying to remove them **by using VBA user-define function** so that phone_number will contain only 10-digits. RightNow I am doing it manually by one by one replace. These are  my phone_number:-

```
+91-9999998989
+-919999999999
-919999999999
-91+9999999999
91-9999999999
091-9999999999
9109999999999
0119999999999
011-9999999999
011 9999999999
987 7845789
7894(784752
7842)748592
7844785621and7854789562
987-1457956
987457812579562147853
```

so my output would be:-

```
9999998989
9999999999
9999999999
9999999999
9999999999
9999999999
9999999999
9999999999
9999999999
9999999999
9877845789
7894784752
7842748592
7844785621and7854789562 // this is take first number
9871457956
987457812579562147853 // this will take first 10 digit
```

I think, I needs to use regular expression. Please help me for creating function for that. your help will be grateful for me.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service, have a go and if you encounter any specific issues, post a question. Also, google VBA regex and this is the first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: @Gareth- Yes, I've difficulty to creating the Regular Expression for that. I am new in VBA excel. Please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: Using left(string, 10) on the results you get from the function I gave you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28609467/how-to-create-macro-using-replace-function) should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code is considering your numbers are in column A and it removed all non number characters.

```
Sub OnlyNumber()
Dim s As String
Dim ReturnVal As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

ReturnVal = ""
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For c = 1 To lastRow
        s = Range("A" & c).Value
            For i = 1 To Len(s)
                If Mid(s, i, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, i, 1) <= "9" Then
                ReturnVal = ReturnVal + Mid(s, i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
        If Len(ReturnVal) > 10 And Len(ReturnVal) <= 14 Then
            Range("A" & c).Value = Right(ReturnVal, 10)
            ElseIf Len(ReturnVal) > 14 Then
                Range("A" & c).Value = Left(ReturnVal, 10)
                ElseIf Len(ReturnVal) = 10 Then
                    Range("A" & c).Value = ReturnVal
                    Else
                    MsgBox ("Not defined number structure")
        End If
        ReturnVal = ""
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: @Dubison- I am getting incorrect Phone Numbers. In One Case, I have **91-9910026444** and result would be **9910026444**. But I am getting **9199100264**. Please see my outputs. I am replacing like as -91, +91, +91-, 91- etc. Thanks

Comment: hello, I have updated the code to cover all examples but I dont know if we covered all possibilities. You need to update criterias when you face them in the future with same logic.

Comment: Your Man!. Its work. I am doing manually check and will come back with you soon. Thanks

Comment: no problem mate. just let me know if you face anything.